# Working with Array As New Object does not work

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class, module

my VBA-code is making trouble. I made a Class module called "clsColl" with the Properties. When i declare a variable as "clsColl" everything working fine, but when i declare an array as "clsColl" i get an error 
"Object variable or With block variable not set", if i use this array in another sub, which i called in the first sub.

I made a short example with just the code in it which making trouble.

First my class module "clsColl"

```
Option Explicit

Public name As String

Public weight as single
```

Now the code which is working

```
Sub workingA()

Dim persona As New clsColl

Call workingB(persona)

End Sub

Sub workingB(persona As cls Coll)

persona.name = "phil"

persona.weight = 100

End Sub
```

Now the code which is not working

```
Sub failingA()

Dim persona() As New clsColl

ReDim persona(1 to 5)


Call failingB(persona)

End Sub

Sub failingB(persona() As cls Coll)



persona(1).name = "phil"

persona(1).weight = 100
End Sub
```

I get an error, just by changing my code from using a variable to using an array.

Now i get an error Object variable or With block variable not set" with the second code, but i don't know why. I want to know why using an array as an object is making trouble like this, while using a normal variable is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing in the array you need to populate the array with classes.  Your Dim wont use the new keyword, you'll create new classes and add them into the array.

```
Sub test1()

Dim d As New clsDimension

Dim arrDimensions(5) As clsDimension

Set arrDimensions(0) = d

arrDimensions(0).Breadth = 100
arrDimensions(0).Depth = 200

End Sub
```

or in a similar approach to your post

A class for the array, like so, `clsDimensionArray`

```
Private arrDimensions() As clsDimension

Public Property Get ArrItems(x As Long) As clsDimension
    Set ArrItems = arrDimensions(x)
End Property

Public Sub Create(lngSize As Long)

Dim l As Long
Dim d As clsDimension

ReDim arrDimensions(lngSize - 1)

For l = 0 To UBound(arrDimensions)
    Set d = New clsDimension
    Set arrDimensions(l) = d
    Set d = Nothing
Next l

End Sub
```

and using like so

```
Sub test1()

Dim arrDimensions As New clsDimensionArray

arrDimensions.Create (100)

arrDimensions.ArrItems(90).Depth = 50
arrDimensions.ArrItems(90).Breadth = 100

End Sub
```

Keeps it nice and tidy :o)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your code line

```
Dim persona As New clsColl
```

is a combination of

```
Dim persona As clsColl
If persona Is Nothing Then Set persona = New clsColl
```

and it is bad practice using that combining syntax at all, at least in my opionion.

Now for the array this cannot work anymore as each array item must be `Set` to be an `clsColl` object first:

```
Sub notMorefailingA()
 Dim persona() As clsColl
 Dim i As Integer
 ReDim persona(1 To 5)
 For i = 1 To 5
  Set persona(i) = New clsColl
 Next
 Call notMorefailingB(persona)
End Sub

Sub notMorefailingB(persona() As clsColl)
 persona(1).name = "phil"
 persona(1).weight = 100
End Sub
```